# SAPUI5 FileUploader Maximum File Size Alert

Tags: sapui5

When using the standard [SAPUI5 FileUploader](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.unified.FileUploader) , is it possible to display a notification when the `maximumFileSize` property is exceeded?

As I see it, the uploader simply won't accept the file if the limit is exceded.

Thanks for your help!

Example

```
<FileUploader
    maximumFileSize="{Config>/maximumFileSize}"
    uploadComplete="onAttachmentUploadComplete">
    ....
</FileUploader>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploader in your view:

```
  <FileUploader
       maximumFileSize="{Config>/maximumFileSize}"
       uploadComplete="onAttachmentUploadComplete"
       fileSizeExceed="onFileSizeExceed">
  </FileUploader>
```

Method in your corresponding controller:

```
onFileSizeExceed: function(error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

I think it is up to you to read the error message and show it in a message toast for example.